# How to handle long press on soft keyboard backspace button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitextfield

When I long tap on default keyboard backspace button, sometime it will clear all text, is there any way to clear one by one character only

Answer (score 0):

You can handle that using the textField shouldChangeCharactersIn delegate method as follow:

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty {
        if range.length != 1 {
            if let val: String = textField.text {
                if !val.isEmpty {
                    let newStr: NSString = val as NSString
                    if newStr.length > 0 {
                        let updatedString: String = newStr.substring(to: newStr.length - 1)
                        textField.text = updatedString
                    }
                }
            }

            return false
        }
    }

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UITextFieldDelegate's` **`textField(_:shouldChangeCharactersIn:replacementString:)`** method like so,

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    if string.isEmpty {
        textField.text?.removeLast()
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```